# Index labels removed when deleting rows, do I want to fix this?

Tags: r, indexing, row, rows, delete-row

I deleted rows from my R dataframe and now the index numbers are out of order. For example, the row-index was 1,2,3,4,5 before but now it is 2,3,4 because I deleted rows 1 and 5.

Do I want to change the index labels from 2,3,4 to 1,2,3 on my new dataframe?

If so, how do I do this?
If not, why not?

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mid-American_Conference"
pg <- read_html(url) # Download webpage
pg

tb <- html_table(pg, fill = TRUE) # Extract HTML tables as data frames
tb

macdf <- tb[[2]]


macdf <- subset(macdf, select=c(1,2,5))


colnames(macdf) <- c("School","Location","NumStudent")


macdf <- macdf[-c(1,8),]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the labels from `"2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "9"  "10" "11" "12" "13" "14"` to `"1"  "2"  "3"  "4"  "5"  "6"  "7"  "8"  "9"  "10" "11" "12"` using:
`row.names(macdf) <- 1:nrow(macdf)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this-

```
> library(data.table)
> subset(setDT(macdf,row.names),select=-rn)
```

OR

```
rownames(macdf) <- NULL
```